# Shiny algorithm help for showing/clearing filters based on dropdown

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, shiny

I need help in determining an algorithm for dynamic filtering

The algorithm should do:

```
1) Get the input region.csv from user
2) Read list of countries and states from the input table
3) Create a drop-down based on values (c("None", "Country,"State"))
4) Now, when I click None- nothing should come, Country- Only country filter should appear, state-Both country and state. 
5) When I click back Country or None, the existing filters of state or country should disappear based on selection.
```

I was able to do first 4 steps. But I couldn't clear the the existing filters when the user clicks back country or None. I tried conditional panels but couldn't accomplish this. Is there any easy way to do this?

EDIT: Code and data

Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E9dbtOMm1-7ZjIHu3Ra_NyFBHrCQdITG2_xuMIMKDOs/edit?usp=sharing

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  navbarPage(

    "DumDum",
    tabPanel("Engine",
             bootstrapPage(

               fileInput("file_attr", "Door attributes:"),
               selectInput("select", label = "Level of Normalization", choices = list("None", "Country", "State"), selected = "None"),

               uiOutput('output_values')
             )
    )
  )
))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  #Reading Input Files 
  data_attr <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file_attr
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)    
  })

  #Filter interactivity

  #Reading Lists
  countries <- reactive({
    if(is.null(data_attr()$Country)){return()}
    data_attr()$Country
  })

  states <- reactive({
    if(is.null(data_attr()$State)){return()}
    data_attr()$State
  })


  #Filters based on Level of normalization


  observeEvent(input$file_attr,{

    output$output_values <- renderUI({
      if (is.null(input$select)){return()}

      switch(input$select,
             "None" = h3("No normalization selected"),
             "Countries" = selectizeInput('show_vars', 'Country Filter', choices = c("Select All","None", unique(countries())), multiple = TRUE),
             "States" = selectizeInput('show_vars_state', 'State Filter', choices = c("Select All","None", unique(states())), multiple = TRUE))
    })

  })   

})
```

Filters not appearing when user clicks "Country" in the drop-down field. Also, is there a way to make state filter disappear if we click Country (I mean if I click Country, only country filter should come; State- both Country and State filters should appear)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell what you are doing wrong, as we cannot see your code. But if I understood you correctly, you want to generate different outputs based on an input from selectInput panel. In that case my suggestion would be to use uiOutput and redner output options from the server side. Example:

**in ui.R**

```
selectInput("filter","Choose a filter",
            choices =list("None","Countries","States"), selected = NULL),
uiOutput("output_values")
```

**in server.R**

```
output$output_values <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$filter))
      return()

switch(input$filter,
       "None" = whatever you want to output for none,
       "Countries" = whatever you want to output for countries,
       "States" = whatever you want to output for states)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Hrant. I added the code and data. I am not able to get filters work for Countries and States using switch(). Also, when I click state, both country and state filters should appear and when I click back Country, existing state filter should disappear. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. It does not work because the name of your options in choices are not the same as in switch. Just change the "Countries" in switch to "Country" and "States" to "State" and it will work fine. As for the second questions, yes, it is quite possible, you just need to copy the "Country" selectizeInput, and paste it in "State". However, in order to show both selectizeInputs you need to put them in some kind of layout function (e.g. flowLayout). It will work fine then.

Comment: Here is how it will look like (with both corrections):
switch(input$select,
             "None" = h3("No normalization selected"),
             "Country" = selectizeInput('show_vars', 'Country Filter', choices = c("Select All","None", unique(countries())), multiple = TRUE),
             "State" = flowLayout(selectizeInput('show_vars_state', 'State Filter', choices = c("Select All","None", unique(states())), multiple = TRUE),
             selectizeInput('show_vars', 'Country Filter', choices = c("Select All","None", unique(countries())), multiple = TRUE)))

Comment: Awesome! flowlayout() worked!! Thanks a lot Hrant! One question: I am new to shiny and am struggling to put the code for every new requirement. For instance, how would I make sure functions like flowlayout() exisits? any documentation for advanced functionality? or some examples for advanced interactions in shiny? Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Rstudio shiny tutorial and articles page is a great start for a beginner. You can find about flowLayout and other layout styles there. [This is](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) the direct link to the article which explains different layout options. But generally, if you struggle with some functionality I would suggest to find a somewhat similar app (probably on [Shiny gallery](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/)) and read its code. It mostly helps.

Comment: Hi @hrant Could you please check the problem I have with your solution. Posted as a separate question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922738/need-help-in-an-algorithm-for-shiny-dynamic-ui-with-multiple-interactions  Thanks!